# Ideal way to add 'season' column to dataframe of NFL plays?

Tags: python, pandas

So I was able to solve this problem on my own, but feel like I've done so in a horribly inefficient way. I'm hoping that someone might be able to offer an alternative solution since this cannot be the ideal method.

I have data for every NFL play since the 2009 season. The dataset includes includes a column for game date but does not include a column for the season, so I would like to create one. Sometimes the NFL has games in January, so I cannot simply calculate this based on the year.

Here is the horribly inefficient solution I came up with:

```
# Create list of season years
season_years = [2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]

# Initialize dictionary of seasons
seasons = {}

# Iterate over season years to add start and end dates to seasons dictionary
# Used Mar 1 and Feb 28 as start and end dates due to Super Bowl being played in early Feb every year
for year in season_years:
    seasons[year] = {'start': str(year) + '-03-01','end': str(year + 1) + '-02-28'}

# Turn seasons dictionary into dataframe
seasons_df = pd.DataFrame(seasons).transpose()

# Convert start and end dates in dataframe to datetime objects
seasons_df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(seasons_df['start'])
seasons_df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(seasons_df['end'])

# Initialize new column 'season' with None values
data['season'] = None

# Iterate over season years, add year to season column if game date is between start and end for that season
for year in season_years:
    data.loc[pd.to_datetime(data['game_date']).between(seasons_df.loc[year,'start'],seasons_df.loc[year,'end']),'season'] = year
```

So this works, but it's kinda rough that I have to iterate over a Python list in order to create the new column. There must be a better way.

EDIT: Data can be downloaded from kaggle here: https://www.kaggle.com/maxhorowitz/nflplaybyplay2009to2016/version/6?

Comment: please add some data and an expected output to, so we can replicate the issue.

Comment: Just added a link to the sample data! Expected output would be a new column containing the season of the game in which each play occurred. A game played on January 3, 2016 should have 2015 as its season. You can use my code to see what the output should look like, I just want to know if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to generate the boundaries for the seasons, and then use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) to assign each game date to a season:

```py
bins = pd.date_range('2009-03-01', periods=10, freq=pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1))
bins = pd.Series(bins, index=bins.year)
data['season'] = pd.cut(df['game_date'], bins, labels=bins.index[:-1]).astype(int)
```

where `bins` looks like the following:

```py
# print bins
2009   2009-03-01
2010   2010-03-01
2011   2011-03-01
2012   2012-03-01
2013   2013-03-01
2014   2014-03-01
2015   2015-03-01
2016   2016-03-01
2017   2017-03-01
2018   2018-03-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The result on a set of random game dates:

```py
# print data.sample(10).sort_values('game_date')
      game_date  season
77   2010-03-19    2010
177  2010-06-27    2010
547  2011-07-02    2011
720  2011-12-22    2011
775  2012-02-15    2011
847  2012-04-27    2012
888  2012-06-07    2012
1636 2014-06-25    2014
1696 2014-08-24    2014
2010 2015-07-04    2015
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thank you!